# Bring back a dead datacenter: repair or rebuild

Tags: cassandra

I had Cassandra cluster running across two data centers, for some reason, one data center was taken down for a while, and now I'm planning to bring it back. I'm thinking about two approaches: 
One is to start up all Cassandra nodes of this data center and run "nodetool repair " on each node one by one. But It looks like 'repair' takes long time. I had an experience to repair 6GB data on a node before, it took me 5 hours on one node (3 nodes cluster). I have much more data on the cluster now, can't image how long it will take. 
So I'm thinking if I can run re-build instead of repair. I can delete all old data on this data center and re-build it as adding a new data center. But not sure if it works and how performance would be.

Any idea on it? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data center was down for more than 10 days then rebuild is the only option. This has to do with the [tombstones](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DistributedDeletes). I am not 100% sure how that works across different data centers, but if you have a server that was down for more than 10 days, any data that has been deleted in the live server has been tombstoned and kept there for 10 days, then removed completely. If all suddenly your downed server wakes up from the sleep, with all deleted data not tombstoned, then it will be repopulated back to the ring via read repair or regular repair operation.

Another thing to consider, is how much data has changed/deleted since the datacenter went down. If a lot, then it obviously it is less work to rebuild. If not then maybe repair will be faster.

You can create another datacenter, add nodes to it with `auto_bootstrap: false` and then run `nodetool rebuild <live dc name>`

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Roman, I faced same issue and I run rebuild command ,but it is so slow in syncing data , is there is any way to sync data in faster manner. As I have data around 50GB on each node (3 node cluster ,with R.F 2). I already stop inserting new data buy sync is too slow.